# `No metadata found in this model` error when import my trained model in Android Studio

Tags: python, android-studio, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I trained my CNN model on two species and changed it to tf-lite from `keras`. But when I tried to follow this YouTube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_XOVkjXQbU&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9znUgvI7lFPE-v5Vw4mGwG&index=4%3E) to use my model in Android Studio:

In this link they teach us to how to use tf-lite model in Android Studio for classification of images. But when I put my model in their code I get the following error :

```py
No metadata found in this model
```

The screenshot of the error is:

[image: No metadata found in this model]

Can someone help me here what to do now?

Comment: So,have you added [metadata](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata) to the file?

Comment: Sir, i don't know what metadata does. i just followed internet to learn and train the model and turn it into tflite file.